# Efficient method of Permission control

Tags: android, performance

I have searched but couldn't figure it out the best efficient method.
Here is the overall scenario: I am accessing STORAGE in various activities, Should I check the permissions at the startup of the app then never check permission through out the whole session or every time I am using the service I should check the permission?

Answer (score 1):

You should check user's permission every time before you use the service because user can revoke permission at any time via Settings.

Comment: I know about that, but how much checking permission adds computation to application?

Comment: I thought you asked about whether you should do it at app start up or every time before the service, not about the computational overload. Probably somebody with android framework knowledge (and algorithm behind permission checking) can provide the answer. As an application developer, what I know is that you definitely should check user permission every time before you use API (which requires the permission) and this is the best practce.